# Pasting tables to spreadJS without losing the formatting

Tags: javascript, tinymce, spreadjs

I have been trying to paste a table from my tinyMCE text editor to SpreadJS. 
I am using a custom made clipboard instead of the default one for this operation, and on copy, table values(text, html) from tinyMCE are successfully passed to the SpreadJS clipboard as well. but as i try to paste it in SpreadJS only the text is appearing in cells. Is there any way i can get this done ? below is the custom paste function which I am using.

```
spread.commandManager().register('custompastefunction', {
                  canUndo: true,
                  execute: (context, options, isUndo) => {
                     //setting the contents copied from tinymce to spreadJS clipboard here.
                     designer.actions.doAction("paste", spread, 0 /* All */);
                     }                     
                  }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a member of GrapeCity’s Technical Engagement team who Supports SpreadJS. It is not possible to create a custom copy/paste function using SpreadJS to copy/paste from tinyMCE. To be able to do this you would have to create your own parser based on what data you would want. If you have any other questions feel free to reach out to our support team.
Best, 
Mackenzie